# What are the "numbers of years up/down" in a mutual fund performance sheet?

Tags: mutual-funds, yahoo-finance

I'm reading a mutual fund's performance sheet on [Yahoo Finance](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/pm?s=PGWAX%20Performance). In the "performance overview" table I can't understand what the "Number of Years Up" (and down) means for that analysis. I guess it tells the number of years the mutual fund went well, but "up" or "down" from what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**"Year Up(down)"** - End of the year figure was greater(lesser) than at the start of the year.

If you go down to the `Annual Total Return (%) History ()` chart, you can see it for yourself.